# How to color only one meaning of variable histogram ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to make several histograms which are colored by only one meaning of one variable. Something like this

[image]

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=value, fill=attribute)) + geom_histogram()
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/plotting-background-data-for-groups-with-ggplot2

Comment: @MrFlick post it as an answer so we don't have all these answer-less questions that are still useful to have onSO